# Column widths with TabularAdapters?

Tags: enthought, canopy, traitsui

Using Enthought Canopy's TraitsUI, I'm using TabularAdapters to display some Arrays, but they always produce evenly proportioned column widths...I'd like to make some widths smaller than others, but haven't found any simple way yet...Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to control the widths of the columns is to override the `get_width()` method of the `TabularArrayAdapter`.  For example,

```
import numpy as np
from traits.api import HasTraits, Array
from traitsui.api import View, Item, TabularEditor
from traitsui.tabular_adapter import TabularAdapter


test_dtype = np.dtype([('x', 'int'),
                       ('y', 'int'),
                       ('r', 'float')])


class TestArrayAdapter(TabularAdapter):

    columns = [(name, idx) for idx, name in enumerate(test_dtype.names)]

    even_bg_color = 0xF0F4FF

    def get_width(self, object, name, col):
        widths = {0: 50, 1: 50, 2: 150}
        return widths[col]


class Test(HasTraits):

    array1 = Array(dtype=test_dtype)

    view = \
        View(
            Item(name='array1', show_label=False,
                 editor=TabularEditor(adapter=TestArrayAdapter())),
            resizable=True,
        )


a1 = np.array([(10, 20, 1.5), (15, 31, 2.4), (14, 11, 1.9), (21, 13, 2.5)],
              dtype=test_dtype)
test = Test(array1=a1)
test.configure_traits()
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]